# jquery mobile how to clear text in Textarea?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery mobile, and I have a input form with clear text button.

ex) `<input type="text" name="" id="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" />`

Then What about the Textarea tag ?

```
<textarea name="" cols="" rows=""  data-clear-btn="true"></textarea>
```

This does not working.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

data-clear-btn is only for textinput, not for textareas.

If you want a similar function, you must create a button near the text area, and clear that programically on button click, setting val('') to the textarea.

```
    <textarea id="myTextarea" name="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <a id="clrTextarea" data-role="button" href="#" onclick="clearTextarea()">Clear</a>

<script>
function clearTextarea(){
  $("#myTextarea").val('');
}
</script>
```

If you want the same efect than data-clear-btn in textinputs, you must hide the button when the textarea is empty, and show it when the textarea has data, with an onChange event over the textarea. Also you can put the button over a textarea's corner using css, and make it translucent when the mouse is not over it, with a hover tag in the css.

Answer (score -2):

```
HTML:
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
<input type="text" />
<a data-role="button" href="#">Click to Change Input's Value</a>
</div>
</div>

jQuery Script:
$('a').bind('click', function () {
$('input').val('');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Little more explanation might help out fellow programmers to understand why and how things work.

Comment: The question was maybe unclear but is about how to get a data clear button in a text area, not how to clear one imho.